# Erlang - connecting to postgreSQL on OpenShift

Tags: postgresql, erlang, openshift

I'm trying to connect to database by [pgsql](https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql) module. But I have **eacces** error. Database in command line client works normaly.
It's a piece of a connecting code (maybe you can advise me how to do this code better):

```
init([]) ->
case os:getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST") of
    false ->
        Host = "127.0.0.1";
    Host ->
        ok
end,
case os:getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME") of
    false ->
        User = "chat_admin";
    User ->
        ok
end,
case os:getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD") of
    false ->
        Password = "1234";
    Password ->
        ok
end,
case os:getenv("PGDATABASE") of
    false ->
        Database = "chat_database";
    Database ->
        ok
end,
Port = 5432,
io:format("DB: ~s ~s ~s ~s ~w~n", [Host, User, Password, Database, Port]),
{ok, C} = pgsql:connect(Host, User, Password, [{database, Database}, {port, Port}]),
{ok, C}.
```

Program shows this line:

```
DB: 127.10.206.130 adminyp4clna TDpRnwsUeJFP chat 5432
```

And then it dies with error stack:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{case_clause,{error,{{shutdown,   failed_to_start_child,chatserver_db,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},[{pgsql_sock,command,2,[{file,"src/pgsql_sock.erl"},{line,163}]},{gen_
server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,639}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}}},{chats
erver_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}},[{chatserver,ensure_started,1,[{file,"chatserver.erl"},{line,14}]},{chatserver,start,0,[{file,"chatserver.erl"},{line,7}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it is a bad smell to use variables matched inside `case`. `case` is an expression, that returns value, so it is better to write something like.

```
Database = case ... of ...
```

For a second, I wanted to point out, that you have uninitialized variables and then I saw that you print them. Only after that I saw, that you match them inside cases :)

Secondly, you have a lot of duplication in your code. With every parameter, you have hardcoded default value, so you can extract the `case` into a function:

```
env_or_default(Env, Default) ->
    case os:getenv(Env) of
        false -> Default;
        Value -> Value
    end.
```

And then call it like this:

```
Database = env_or_default("PGDATABASE", "chat_database").
```

Thirdly, it would be good to use Erlang config files, instead of reading os variables. I explained them in my other answer on SO: [config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413887/how-to-load-the-resource-file-in-erlang/25424311#25424311).

Unfortunately, I don't have answer for your main question about the database :/ I tried exactly the same syntax, with the same parameters and it returns `{ok, Pid}` for me, so there must be some kind of spelling mistake in the connection details.

If I specify non existing user, I get another error:

```
{error,{error,fatal,<<"28000">>,
          <<"role \"postgres\" does not exist">>,[]}}
```

Your error `eacces` might be caused by running your application and `psql` as different unix users.